# PDE Describing The Growth of Bone Matrix

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

$v$ - volume, $x$ - position, $t$ - time. Bone Growth is proportional to surface area of growth sites --> $ dv/dt$ ~$\pi$ $r^2$~$(r^3)$^(2/3)~$v$^(2/3).       I have the equation: $v_x + v_t $= kv ^2/3$, $k is a real number. (Which i found by taking a total derivative of volume with respect to time).Here the subscriptes denote partial derivatives. $k$ is a real valued scalar. After non-dimensionalizing this equation using scales: $x=x^*X, t=t^*T,v=v^*\hat V$, I derived the dimensionless equation:

$\hat V^.66667 $ = $\hat V_X+\hat V_T$. With initial conditions:$\hat V(X,0)$=$0 $ and $V(0,T)=1$. Now I need to use the method of characteristics to solve this equation, but I'm having trouble with it. How to you derive the characteristic curves? I know they are something like $T=X+C$ , where C is a real scalar. Also, using characteristics we  have to solvesolve $V'=V^.6667$ which I know how to solve, Basically I'm just curious about how one would use method of characteristics to solve this PDE. PS: Sorry for the messy notation it's been a while since I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve $u_{t} + u_{x} = u^{2/3}$ ($u = \hat{v}$) then your characteristic equations are

\begin{align}
\frac{dt}{ds} &= 1 \quad (1)\\
\frac{dx}{ds} &= 1 \quad (2)\\
\frac{du}{ds} &= u^{2/3} \quad(3)
\end{align}

Using the first two ODEs to eliminate $s$, we find

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= 1 \\
\implies x(t) &= t + x_{0}
\end{align}

The solving the third

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt} &= u^{2/3} \\
\implies 3u^{1/3} &= t + f(x_{0}) \\
&= t + f(x-t) \\
\implies u(x,t) &= \bigg(\frac{t + f(x-t)}{3} \bigg)^{3}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, I am actually sure this is the correct answer. I will look into this in more depth and may have an additional comment. Thanks again for your time. Looks very nice.

Comment: In general question, do we need to focus on boundary conditions here?